# Pandas: iterate over unique values of a column that is already in sorted order

Tags: python, group-by, pandas

I have constructed a pandas data frame in sorted order and would like to iterate over groups having identical values of a particular column.  It seems to me that the groupby functionality is useful for this, but as far as I can tell performing groupby does not give any guarantee about the order of the key.   How can I extract the unqiue column values in sorted order.

Here is an example data frame:

```
Foo,1
Foo,2
Bar,2
Bar,1
```

I would like a list ["Foo","Bar"] where the order is guaranteed by the order of the original data frame.  I can then use this list to extract appropriate rows.  The sort is actually defined in my case by columns that are also given in the data frame (not included in the example above) and so a solution that re-sorts will be acceptable if the information can not be pulled out directly.

Comment: Can you give code demonstrating why this is failing in your case? My experience has been that after a `groupby` in Pandas, the new data frames *are* in the same order as in the original, ungrouped data frame. If you can provide a small amount of code that constructs a toy data frame, performs the grouping, and then display the issue at hand, it would be helpful.

Comment: If you just need a unique list of the values in a column in the same order, why not just use this: `df.c1.unique()`, where c1 is the name of the column you want to unique values for.

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use unique on the column which will preserve the order (unlike numpy's unique, it doesn't sort):

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]: 
     0  1
0  Foo  1
1  Foo  2
2  Bar  2
3  Bar  1

In [12]: df[0].unique()
Out[12]: array(['Foo', 'Bar'], dtype=object)
```

Then you can access the relevant rows using groupby's `get_group`:

```
In [13]: g = df.groupby([0])

In [14]: g.get_group('Foo')
Out[14]: 
     0  1
0  Foo  1
1  Foo  2
```

Comment: When I try to use the above example, I get "array" is not defined. Is it defined somewhere?

Comment: @aging_gorrila the out lines are *output* lines (from ipython). The DataFrame is defined by reading the csv in the above question, but your own would work.

Comment: `array` simply refers to an underlying NumPy `ndarray` (`np.ndarray`) that Pandas utilizes to store your data