# Pandas: iterate over unique values of a column that is already in sorted order using For loop

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have constructed a dataframe in a sorted manner, and now need to write a code that iterates over Each unique Item So say the data set is

```
a,1
a,2
a,3
b,1
b,2
```

Id need the code to loop over the df in such a way that 2 new dfs are formed using the unique values in column[0].

```
a,1
a,2
a,3
```

and

```
b,1
b,2
```

Something similar is done here :[Pandas: iterate over unique values of a column that is already in sorted order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20664980/pandas-iterate-over-unique-values-of-a-column-that-is-already-in-sorted-order)

but id need a for loop to get the output for my function after its run over every possible dataframe formed .

so itd look something like this wwith 2 functoions f and g running over column[0]

so, the functions would be defined within the loop

```
col  a  b
f    1  1
g    2  2
```

Tried using( AG is the name of the column with Key values ):

```
for AG, V in df.groupby[('AG')]:print(V)
```

Comment: `for k,v in df.groupby('col0'): print(v)`

Comment: could you elaborate

Comment: You should try that command, with the actual column name

Comment: k and v would be the column names, yes? so, in my case that could be the index and c2 ?

Comment: k as the key and vas the resulting dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Group the dataframe by the letter column and unpack to get your dataframes :

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',', header=None,names=['letter','number'])

 #unpack dataframe
 #the groupby holds the group key, with the grouped variables
 #in this case we know that there are only two groupings (a and b)
(key1, df1),(key2, df2) = df.groupby("letter",as_index=False)
```

Comment: In this case theres only 2, would this hold good in the case that there are hundreds of key values.

Comment: (key1, df1),(key2, df2) = df.groupby("letter",as_index=False), how does the LHS of this line work.

Comment: Python has a feature called unpacking that allows the values on the RHS to be assigned to variables on the LHS, as long as they are matched properly. For groupings more than two, you have to resort to a for loop, as @QuangHoang explained in the comments